# Whats the logic between MAR, MBR and Control Bus

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

Control Unit has MAR and MBR registers. so MAR emits instruction to address bus so that the specific cell in the memory is activated. MAR also emits READ or WRITE command to control bus. MBR emit data for WRITE actions to data bus.

Question is how does the control bus communicate between MAR and MBR to know whether it is a write or read command. And once the cell is activated, how does data is being written or read?

I know CPU is smart... and computer bus is smarter... but there has to be logic to it...

Answer (score 1):

The RAM typically has a input pin called *MW* for "memory write" (maybe with inverted logic, then written with an overbar), to distinguish between read and write operations.

Control will probably use an extra wire to the RAM. In theory, you *could* use an usused high address bit for that, too, but I guess that would be considered to be a very questionable design - in fact "invalid" memory addresses are used for other strange things, like talking to non-memory devices such as line printers.

An address decoder will select the appropriate memory cell.

After that, the rest will depend on the *MW* bit... on the writing side, if it's static RAM (SRAM), you can use *MW* for enabling ("gating") the flipflop *S* (set) pin. On the reading side, you could use a transmission gate to connect or disconnect the RAM output from the data bus (logic gates won't do here, as the RAM output has to be *decoupled* from the data bus, unless you are actually reading values).